# MongoDB document key case sensitive nature

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

A collection with document as:

```
{
 "EMPLOYEE_NAME":"test",
 "EMPLOYEE_DEPT":"fin"
}
```

In model,  using:

```
@JsonProperty("Employee_name")
private String EMPLOYEE_NAME;
```

OR

```
@JsonProperty("EMPLOYEE_NAME")
private String EMPLOYEE_NAME;
```

returns in API response:

```
{"employee_NAME":"test","Employee_Name":"test"}
```

Result is repeated twice. One with string before '_' as lower case and rest as UPPER CASE and other as whatever value I give in `@JsonProperty`.

if the collection has:

```
{
     "employee_name":"test",
     "employee_dept":"fin"
    }
```

Then, API response gives key as whatever I give in `@JsonProperty`

Basically, I have two questions.
- Does MongoDB conventionally should not have documents with keys as all UPPER CASE?
- How should I handle @JsonProperty to make my API response give my desired key of response irrespective of key of mongoDB Json doc (especially if all keys are all UPPER CASE. I can handle lower case alright?

Comment: Mongodb: by convention or restrictions [Mentioned here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#field-names) does not prevent you from having field names as UPPER_CASE. I think It has to do with Jackson mapping (simply put the annotations over getters/setter) to correct it. [More about this](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1609)

Comment: I am using Lombok to generate getter and setter on the fly during implementation. Not creating getters and setter exclusively